# Auto Rotation of Secret Key and Access Key in AWS using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to rotate Access Key and Secret Key automatically using Lambda. (boto3)

Condition is like:

1. At 85 day of key age user will get a Email for warning
2. At 90 day Age user will receive a new credential via Email.
3. At 95th day the old key gets deactivate automatically.(user need to login via fresh Access key and secret key)

   Is this is possible using AWS lambda? Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: Note also that AWS provide Lambda functions for [rotating secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_available-rotation-templates.html), which you can potentially adapt.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Writing code is **use-case specific**. You can start writing it yourself and then ask again if you have any specific issue.

But generally, to implement **periodic rotation** you would use:

- [CloudWatch Event scheduled rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html)

The rule would automatically call a target, i.e. your lambda function, which would have logic to perform the rotation. For that boto3's [create_access_key_pair](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.User.create_access_key_pair) along with deleting/disable existing keys ([delete_access_key](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.delete_access_key) or [update_access_key](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.delete_access_key) to disable).

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is definitely possible, the AWS SDK has a action for [list_access_keys](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_access_keys).

If you created a [CloudWatch event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html) you could trigger this Lambda every day. Once you call the request you can see all access keys with a `UserName` value and a `CreateDate` value.

By doing a comparison between the 2 dates you could then perform the requested action.

- Using either [SES](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html) or [SNS](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html) notify the user at 85 days
- Use the [create_access_key](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_access_key) method at 90 days
- Use the [delete_access_key](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.delete_access_key) at 95 days.